# Node Pool creation problem in GKE: m1-megamem-96 not found in europe-west1

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am tyring to create a Node Pool in GKE and get the following error:

```
Invalid machine type m1-megamem-96 in zone europe-west1-c: googleapi: 
Error 404: The resource 'projects/<ProjectName>/zones/europe-west1-c/machineTypes/m1-megamem-96' was not found, notFound.
```

But according to [this](https://www.instance-pricing.com/provider=gcp/instance=m1-megamem-96/) link `europe-west1` should support `m1-megamem-96`.

The error message doesn't seem to give the complete reason.

Any help in debugging will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Machine type M1 is available in the region europe-west1, not in the zone europe-west1-c. Refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones#available) to know which machine types are available in which zone.

From the link above, the sortable table lets you select different options to see where resources are available. For example, you can select Europe from the Select a location drop-down menu, and M1 from the Select a machine type drop-down menu to see a list of zones where M1 machines are available in Europe.

Not all machine types are guaranteed to be available in all zones all the time. To ensure that a machine type is available when you need it, you can preemptively reserve the machine type in a certain zone. For information about reserving predefined machine types in a specific zone, see [Reserving zonal resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources).

Comment: Did you had time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If yes, Please consider to accept and upvote it. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)